# Anyone understand the quality of hash?

Tags: perl, hash

The "quality" of a hash is defined as the total number of comparisons needed to access every element once, relative to the expected number needed for a random hash. The value can go over 100%.

The total number of comparisons is equal to the sum of the squares of the number of entries in each bucket.  For a random hash of "<n"> keys into "<k"> buckets, the expected value is:

```
n + n ( n - 1 ) / 2 * k
```

What exactly is the quality of hash??

Comment: Where did that formula come from?  Is is supposed to represent how many comparisons are required to find all 'n' keys with 'k' buckets?  If so, that adds up to 460, which seems about 450 iterations worse than a simple array at the worst case, and 455 iterations worse than an average case with an array.  I think something's wrong there.

Comment: It's from `perldoc Devel::Peek`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  It's written as `n + n ( n - 1 ) / 2k` in the docs, which is more like `n + n * ( n - 1 ) / ( 2 * k )`, which yields a more reasonable result.

Comment: @DavidO ,I don't understand this formula..

Comment: You may find http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/10/01/hashes.html useful.  Hash lookups and insertions occur in an average constant time as long as buckets have fairly even distribution.  Mastering Algorithims with Perl (O'Reilly) also discusses hashes as well as an introduction to Big-O theory (a notation that tries to quantify worst case complexity, along with siblings that handle best case and average case).

Comment: @DavidO ,in my opinion it should be `n(n+k)/2k`.Means for `n` keys into `n` buckets,the expected value should be `n`,which is right of course.

Comment: @new_perl let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1863/discussion-between-davido-and-new-perl)

Comment: Not sure this question should be tagged as **Perl**?, seems irrelevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring a hash functions quality (for use with maps/assosiative arrays)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729730/measuring-a-hash-functions-quality-for-use-with-maps-assosiative-arrays)

Answer (score 4):

It is a measure for how "evenly distributed" the hash is. Ideally, the hash function would place everything into its own bucket, but that does not happen because you cannot have that many buckets (and even then there are hash collisions, so that distinct values still end up in the same bucket).

The performance of the hash (ideally just going to up a bucket and looking at the single element in there) degrades when you have buckets with many elements in them: If that happens, you have to linearly go through all of them.

A quality of 100% is what you would expect for a hash filled with random data. In that case, all buckets should be equally full. If you have more than 100%, your data is unevenly hashed, and lookups take more time.

Comment: Not all hash implementations have collisions "end up in" the same bucket -- collisions of *hash values* may be resolved without chaining (generally some form of probe and guaranteed availability of buckets).